# Wordpress Orderby not working

Tags: events, wordpress

So I've been trying like a madman, to organize my events (which are posts) by one of the meta_values with absolutely no success:

Here's the code (Trying to organize Tribe Events by the meta_key "kind" which values are either A, B, or C)

```
<?php 

  global $post;

  $current_date = date('j M Y');
  $end_date = $current_date;

  $get_posts = tribe_get_events(array(
    'start_date'=>$end_date,
    'end_date'=>$end_date,
    'posts_per_page'=>3,
    'order'=>'ASC',
    'meta_key'=>'kind',
    'orderby'=>'meta_value', // Each post either has A, B, or C, set as it's meta value, yet it displays the post by date (which is normal), but ignores the meta_values
    ));

  foreach($get_posts as $post) {setup_postdata($post);

?>

      <li>
        <p class="date">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="month"> <?php echo tribe_get_start_date($post->ID, false, 'M'); ?></span></a> 
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="day"> <?php echo date('d'); ?></span></a>
        </p>
        <p class="info">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a> <?php the_field('kind'); ?> <br><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 50); ?>...</p>      
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </li>

<?php } //endforeach ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Even when I try to run a normal query and sort it's still not working (Just incase tribe_get_events is overriding the orderby filter.

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'tribe_events', 'orderby'=> 'meta_value', 'meta_key'=>'kind'));
```

But that still gets me nothing.

Basically I have three kinds of posts, I want the posts for today to show up, but I want them sorted by type. Where type A will show first, B Second, and C third. Since that's the priority of these events. So the result should show, AAB, but instead in the image you can see it's just showing ABA (Ordered by when post was published)

http://cl.ly/image/0W2b2I270d3v

Spent two days on this with no results. I've been on this site and all over google/asking other developers with no solid advice :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have no experience with this plugin, but I can offer my initial observation and hopefully it can help.

public/template-tags/general.php defines tribe_get_events() at line 167, which looks likes it uses TribeEventsQuery::getEvents(). That static function is defined at lib/tribe-event-query.class.php on line 645 and has a $defaults array which orders by $event_date. It looks like the passed array arguments are overridden by that defaults array. Again, no experience with this plugin at all. I just saw @nathansmith tweet about it and downloaded it real quick to take a look at the files. I have no idea why the custom WP_Query didn't work.

I may can take a deeper look at it if this doesn't help.

EDIT: btw the paths are relative to the plugin directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think Adam might be on the right track. I don't know how the plugin does this, but I ran a normal query and looked at the arguments that came out of the results: tribe_events forces the order to be ASC by event_date, even if I supplied arguments otherwise.

You might be better off doing your own sorting on the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

After a long seeking and learning (and I am not wp expert), I found an ultimate solution for this Modern Tribe plugin.
The problem is, that the plugin wants you to use their function to get the posts, but what if you want to have the post inside the main query - this enables you to use the have_posts().
And when you try to set your orderby for that query - it doesn't change.

So, here is the best solution you will find all over the net -
You should update the main class function in lib/tribe-event-query.class.php as described here: http://blog.timoor.info/2015/02/wordpress-posttype-tribeevents-orderby.html

Then your
`query_posts(array('post_type'=> 'tribe_events','orderby' => 'EventRating',`  .....

WILL FINALLY WORK